# Why ConfigurationProperties are not validated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

What is difference between @Value and @ConfigurationProperties injection? Why Value properties are validated and ConfigurationProperties are not?

Answer (score 1):

@Value is a core container feature and it does not provide the same features as type-safe Configuration Properties. It's maybe for that... I think. I currently work (discover) on spring (MVC) and I recommend you to take a look at the [spring reference (Externalized Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)